# How can I trigger container restart when lets-encrypt-nginx-proxy-companion renews my certificate

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt

How can I trigger my custom container restart when [docker-lets-encrypt-nginx-proxy-companion](https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion) renews SSL certificate?

For anyone who may ask, my custom container is not proxied by nginx container connected with docker-lets-encrypt-nginx-proxy-companion by `com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy` label. It is a separate service which needs to be reloaded to handle certificate renewal.

Answer (score 1):

Certbot supports both pre and post renewal commands. Example:

```
certbot renew --pre-hook "service nginx stop" --post-hook "service nginx start"
```

Here is a link to documentation on certbot and containers:

[Restart container when certificate is renewed](https://github.com/adferrand/docker-letsencrypt-dns#restart-containers-when-a-certificate-is-renewed)